# Как вывести в админке django столбец из связи многие ко многим?

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести в админке django столбец из связи многие ко многим?

Пример:

Есть модель  `books` и `author`:

```
class books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Название книги')
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name=u'Год выпуска')
    author = models.ManyToManyField(author)

class author(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Автор')
```

Содержание admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from support.models import books, author

class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'year', 'ЧТО_ТУТ_НАПИСАТЬ?')

admin.site.register(books, BooksAdmin)
```

Что нужно написать, что бы появился третий столбец, в котором будут отображаться авторы книга (через перенос строки).

Comment: Классы с маленькой буквы - очень плохая идея.

Answer (score 2):

> Чтобы появился третий столбец, в котором будут отображаться авторы книги через запятую.

```
#models.py

class Books(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Название книги')
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name=u'Год выпуска')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    def author_names(self):
        return u" %s" % (u", ".join([author.full_name for author in self.authors.all()]))
    author_names.short_description=u'Авторы'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Author(models.Model):

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'Автор')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name

#admin.py:

from django.contrib import admin  
from support.models import books, author  

class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    list_display = ('name', 'year', 'author_names')  

admin.site.register(books, BooksAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую - [никак](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

> ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom methods in list_display.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#models.py   python3 django 1.11

from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Автор')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Books(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название книги')
    year = models.IntegerField( verbose_name='Год выпуска')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Books, Author  
from itertools import chain

class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    def author_names(self, obj):
        a = obj.authors.values_list('full_name')
        return list(chain.from_iterable(a))
    list_display = ('name', 'year', 'author_names')  

admin.site.register(Books, BooksAdmin)  
admin.site.register(Author)
```